# Normal completely positive idempotents with range a factor

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose $L$ is a completely positive contraction of $B(H)$ into itself which is idempotent (i.e. $L^2 = L$) and suppose the range of $L$ is a von Neumann factor $M$.
Suppose further that $L$ is normal, so
$$
     L(A) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty S_i A S_i^* 
$$
for $A\in B(H)$. Then $M$ is a type I factor. Has anyone seen a proof of this?  I believe, if the range of $L$ is a von Neumann algebra $R$, then $R$ is atomic.  The key is $L$ is normal.

Comment: Dear Bob: if Nik's answer is satisfactory, you can mark it as "officially accepted", which will take your question off the list of "questions still requiring an answer"

Answer (score 2):

This is in Bruce Blackadar's book, Operator Algebras: Theory of C*-Algebras and Von Neumann Algebras. See Theorem IV.2.2.3.